# Trouble opening a file using PyQt5 getOpenFileName

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qfiledialog

I want the user to open a file, the file name is passed to a function that uses the file for saving some data. I am using PyQt5 getOpenFileName for this:

```
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open Data File")
```

But, I receive this error message: "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)". I am using python 3.7.1 and pyqt 5.9.2. My question is how I can fix this error.

Edit:
Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
import os
def saveSubjectList(FileNamePath,subjectList):
    columns = list(subjectList[0].__dict__.keys())
    vals = []
    for iSub in range(len(subjectList)):
        valsSub = subjectList[iSub].__dict__.values()
        vals.append(valsSub)

    subject_pd = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=columns)
    subject_pd.to_csv(FileNamePath)

def loadSubjectList(FileNamePath):
    csvFile = open(FileNamePath, 'r')
    csvFileArray = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvFile):
        csvFileArray.append(row[1:])

    keys = csvFileArray[0]
    subList = []

    for sub in csvFileArray[1:]:
        subject1 = Subject(sub[0])
        for val, key in zip(sub, keys):
            setattr(subject1, key, val)
        subList.append(subject1)
    for item in range(len(subList)):
        print(subList[item].__dict__)

class Subject:
    def __init__(self, Id):
        self.Id = Id
        self.Name = ""
        self.FrameNumberList = []
        self.Color = [0, 1, 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    subjectList = []
    for i in range(2):
        subject1 = Subject(i)
        subject1.Name = "Subject" + str(i)
        subject1.FrameNumberList = [i, 10, 23, 23]
        subjectList.append(subject1)
    FileNamePath = os.getcwd()
    fileName = 'New'
    fileNameSuffix = 'csv'
    csvPathAndName = os.path.join(FileNamePath, fileName + '.' + 
     fileNameSuffix)
    saveSubjectList(csvPathAndName, subjectList)
    loadSubjectList(csvPathAndName)
```

This is the initial code without getOpenFileName, which works fine. Then I removed the lines from FileNamePath= os.getcwd to csvPathAndName=..., and replaced it with:

```
csvPathAndName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open Data File")
```

because I want the user to be able to create or select the file from anywhere in the computer, but then I get the error.

Comment: Run your script from the command line (CMD)

Comment: I tried that, but I get the "DLL load fail" error. The other thing that I forgot to mention is that before adding getOpenFileName, the script ran without any error. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Post a minimal example showing your problem.

Comment: Please see a sample code in my Edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Miranda In what part of your code do you use QFileDialog?

Comment: @eyllanesc in the edit, after the script I explained where I put QFileDialog. The code that I posted is the one that works fine. Then I remove everything from "FileNamePath= os.getcwd" to "csvPathAndName = os.path.join(FileNamePath, fileName + '.' + fileNameSuffix)" and replace it with the QFileDialog line, and this is when I get the error.

Comment: add `app = QApplication([])` before `csvPathAndName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open Data File")`

Comment: @eyllanesc I added that and now it works. Thank you!